# How to comprehensively change my locale choice after installing antiX?

Tags: system-installation, locale, antix

I've installed antiX Linux (v19.3), with a certain locale (let's say it's xx_XX.UTF-8). After installation, I've had a change of heart and want the locale for all users to be/to default to something else (yy_YY.UTF-8).

How do I make that change *comprehensively* (i.e. leaving no user, app or configuration file believing the locale is or used to be xx_XX.UTF-8)?

Note: Answers about Debian-based distributions in general are also ok.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and select the available locales to be generated for your system. In the next step, select the default locale. This updates `/etc/default/locale` and `/etc/locale.gen`.

Of course users may choose to override the default locale, for example in their personal shell startup files.

Comment: While of course I need to do that - it's the most obvious part (that's covered in other questions).

Comment: @einpoklum It is better to improve the proposed answer than adding your own.

Comment: @GAD3R: Not if the proposed answer is a trivial one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have so far:

- The obvious part: As root, run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. Note: By default, antiX generates a couple dozen popular locales - you don't need them.
- Replace xx_XX.UTF-8 with yy_YY.UTF-8 in `/etc/minstall.conf`.
- For the single user created during installation: Rename the folders in its home directory from the localized names to 'Downloads', 'Pictures', 'Video', 'Documents', 'Music', 'Desktop'.
- In the IceWM launcher menu, select "Refresh Menu". This regenerates the Applications menu entries, which otherwise would stay in language xx

I'm not sure this covers everything though...